# CMD/batch get basename for subfolder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

I want to loop through all subfolders in `c:\my_folder`, check if specified file exist then create (if not exist) folder in `c:\copy` (for example `c:\copy\project1`) and copy mentioned file.

Is it easy to loop through folders in batch file (`for /d %variable in ("path") DO command`),
but variable contains full path. For creating new folder I need only basename for subfolder.
How I can get it? Should I write another for loop when I remove other characters?
Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Joey said.  On the other hand, you could try a completely different approach:

```
XCOPY "C:\my_folder\my_file" "C:\copy" /S /I
```

This will copy the specified file from all subfolders of `C:\my_folder` to `C:\copy` with preserving the structure. Subfolders that do not have `my_file` will not be created in `C:\copy`. The `/S` switch tells `XCOPY` to search for `my_file` in subfolders. The `/I` parameter is there to make sure `C:\copy` should be a folder, before proceeding.

Comment: so, should I type something like that: for /d %%d in (C:\my_folder) do (xcopy %%d\myfile c:\copy /S /I)? I can't check it now, because I'm currently working under Linux machine.

Comment: @matandked: No, just `xcopy`, without any loop. At least, that was what I tried and it worked for me the way I've described in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly you want just the folder name. In that case this is easy:

```
for /d %%d in (C:\my_folder) do echo %%~nxd
```